# Counting how many cells, values, and formulas are in a sheet with Excel

Tags: excel, count, office-2010

Microsoft Word 2010 offers an option to see how many words there are in a document. Is there a similar option in Excel 2010 to see how many cells/values/formulas I have in a specific workbook or a specific sheet?

In Word 2010, the word count can be found in File > Informations > Show all properties. In Excel though, there isn't nearly as much information. Is it hidden somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use the `SpecialCells` property of the `Range` object to find this information.  For example, `ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Count` will return the number of cells containing formulas on the active sheet, and `ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count` will return the number of cells containing constants.  See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx) for more information.

If you wanted totals for an entire workbook, you could loop through the elements of the `Workbook` object's `Worksheets` collection, use the `SpecialCells` property of each `Worksheet` object's `Cells` member to get the numbers you want, and add up the totals.

Comment: That's VBA. Does it mean that it's not integrated in Excel the same way it is in Word? I'm surprised.

Comment: As far as I know, the properties you are looking for are not integrated.  In VBA, the `Workbook` object does have a `BuiltinDocumentProperties` collection that you can use to manipulate the information shown on the Properties page (like Title, Subject, Author, etc.), but the collection doesn't contain the properties that you are looking for.